# What fields uniquely identify a row in Oracle BRM's Account_Nameinfo_T Table?

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to determine a set of fields that uniquely identify a row in Account_Nameinfo_T. Oracle BRM uses no constraints so I cannot determine it that way. Does anyone know these fields? Better yet, does anyone know how I can determine this for other tables in BRM?

(Apparently there is no Oracle-Brm tag in SO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add a bit more information to the (good) answer provided by @Pavel Chernikov.

In general, BRM stores the definition of a class in 3 Data Dictionary tables (namely `DD_OBJECTS_T`, `DD_FIELDS_T` and `DD_OBJECTS_FIELDS_T`) but you should use the Class Browser of the Developer Center to have a convenient, graphical view.

Furthermore, the BRM documentation (under BRM Documentation - Reference - Database reference - Storable class definitions) has extensive information about class definition.

For example we can take a look at the `/account` class:

- in the SQL Mapping section, we can see that it maps to the table `ACCOUNT_T`
- it has an array `PIN_FLD_NAMEINFO` that is mapped to the table `ACCOUNT_NAMEINFO_T`
- therefore, a record in `ACCOUNT_NAMEINFO_T` will be uniquely identified by the couple

  1. `OBJ_ID0`, which can be thought of as a foreign key to the `POID_ID0`(*) of the corresponding record in `ACCOUNT_T`
  2. `REC_ID`, which is called the element ID and is used to differentiate among possible multiple records in `ACCOUNT_NAMEINFO_T` for the same record in `ACCOUNT_T`
- the documentation also gives us a hint of the functional meaning of the element ID

  > array `PIN_FLD_NAMEINFO`: Contact information for account. This array contains any number of contacts with the description for the type of contact. **The element-id is not significant except for the billing contact (1) and mailing contact (2).** The element-id's 3-100 are reserved.
- in case of further nesting, additional elements IDs are used, like `REC_ID2`: for instance, the array `PIN_FLD_PHONES`, within the very same array `PIN_FLD_NAMEINFO`, maps to the table `ACCOUNT_PHONES_T` where a record would be uniquely identified by the triplet (`OBJ_ID0`, `REC_ID`, `REC_ID2`)

(*) Please note that in general, a POID is composed of 4 elements:

1. an ID (`POID_ID0`)
2. a type (`POID_TYPE`)
3. a database number (`POID_DB`)
4. a revision number (`POID_REV`)

However, for a single-DB installation and for the sake of this discussion, we can assume that the ID is sufficient to uniquely identify a record in a given table.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that you know python - I wrote a python wrapper for BRM called `pybrm` which you can install with `pip install pybrm`. Check out the tutorial on [Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pybrm/) if you are interested.

Comment: Great job and exhaustive documentation with `pybrm` @MatthewMoisen!

Answer (score 2):

Combination of OBJ_ID0 an REC_ID is what uniquely identifies a row in ACCOUNT_NAMEINFO_T table.

REC_ID in case of this table normally will be either 1 or 2 (I believe 1 is BILLING and 2 is SERVICE).

The main tables in Oracle BRM (such as ACCOUNT_T, EVENT_T, CONFIG_T) are uniquely identified by POID_ID0.

All sub-tables are uniquely identified by either OBJ_ID0 (when table maps to PIN_FLD_SUBSTRUCT) or combination of OBJ_ID0 and REC_ID (when table maps to PIN_FLD_ARRAY).